# How to change to pose-mode when running a Python script

Tags: python, scripting, pose-mode, command-line

How can I change to pose-mode with a Python script while the whole program is running in the background?
When I use `bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()`, it just shows `PASS_THROUGH`. When manually doing it, I click on the bone, but using `bone.select` or `obj.select_set(True)` doesn't work in the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

To change the 3D Viewport mode use [`bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=MODE)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.mode_set) so you want

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
```

Once you have that you should be able to manipulate the armature in pose mode.